# How to create an animation like the line crossing the button will open up vertically and created a box with jquery, css

Tags: jquery, animation, popup

I wanna create an animation like this

See the structure what i have [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEJoO.jpg)

```
<div class="joinclubbannermobilecontainer" style="display: block;">
    <div class="joinclubborder"></div>
    <div class="joinclubbannerbutton">
        <a>Join</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of a button popup box must be opened but from first the line crossing the button will open up vertically and animated up and down

I tried this code

```
jQuery('.joinclubbannerbutton').click(function(){
    jQuery("#clubpopupoverlay").fadeIn(400);
    jQuery("#clubformoverlay").fadeIn(400); 
    jQuery("#clubformoverlay").animate({height: '250px', 'width':'63%'}, 1000);
    jQuery("#clubformoverlay").animate({marginTop: '-130px'}, 1000);
    jQuery("#clubformoverlay").slideUp();
});
```

But this is not exactly what i want.Any ideas?
[image][image][image]

Comment: Is the line coming from one side (e.g. the left of the screen) or extending both sides from a dot in the middle?

Comment: It must be in the middle of the screen starting from small height like 10px @Daniel Cheung

Comment: Can you draw several diagrams of how you want the animation to go?

Comment: See my updated question @DanielCheung

Comment: So the button first hide behind the line and comes out?

Comment: I showed the process after button click. So at first the line will be shown verically and then it should grow up and down @DanielCheung

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I don't have the slightest idea of what you are achieving :(

Comment: how you imagine such type of animation? How i could animate it like an accordion i could say which is opening and showing the top half and then the bottom half part @DanielCheung